# Same function for different values of members in a structure

Tags: c, function, overloading, structure

I am trying to use the same function for different values of members of a structure in C. Actually, my function is large and I do not want to re-write it again and again. 
So, is there any other way to achieve that?

```
typedef struct {
     int xpos;
     char label[30];
     fielddesc field;
} editordesc;
```

I want to change the xpos and some others members using the same function:

```
void edit(void)
{
   editordesc setf[] = { 5,"Description", 40, 0, plu.rec.DESCRIPTION };
   // code
}

void edit1(void)
{
   editordesc setf[] = { 10,"Date", 50, 10, plu.rec.Date };
   // code
}
```

**Edit:**
I want to use edit() multiple times into my main() and the only thing that I want to change each time is only some values inside setf[]. So is there any alternative way? I do not want to re-write the same function again and again with different names and just only changing the values of setf[]

Comment: Large functions are generally bad, you should consider splitting it up into smaller functions. Which will also help for this problem, as you can then create two different functions that creates different instances of the structure with different values, then call a second function which contains the main part of your old function and pass the structure (or structures) as an argument.

Comment: Wholly tangential to your question: I recommend using braces around the initializers for the `fielddesc` part of the information.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Not to mention extra outer braces because the OP seems to be initializing an array...

Comment: Pass the relevant `editordesc` value as an argument to a revised version of your `edit()` function. If there’s an interface requirement that the function  by takes no argument, then maybe, perhaps (and only under duress), consider whether a global variable can convey information to the function, but it is in every way undesirable

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude — that too (array initialization). Having an array opens up other options (passing an array index into the function), but also opens up questions about “should the array be static so it is initialized just once, not every time the function is called”.

Comment: Could I split up my function if it is already used in my main as a parameter to another function that takes only void?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways.

1. Take structure as parameter to the function.

   ```
   void edit(editordesc var);
   ```

   And call the function two times.
2. Or have array of structure and loop over it.

   ```
   void edit(void)
   {
      editordesc setf[] = {{ 5,"Description", 40, 0, plu.rec.DESCRIPTION },
                       { 10,"Date", 50, 10, plu.rec.Date }};    

       for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(setf)/sizeof(setf[0]); i++) {
            //printf("%d",setf[i].xpos);
            //your code
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Is it possible to use function edit() multiple times into my main() using only one index of editordesc setf[ ] array each time? if not, how could achieve that?